# PAYPAL other payment options issue

Tags: php, paypal

I have integrated pay pal on to my site. Now I want to put option Not have pay pal account?

Because my all user has not pay pal account so they can able to pay directly without creating pay pal account.

Currently i am using pay pal hidden form field technique. anyone let me know which field i have to pass in to form which can display option for do not have pay pal account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the PayPal API.  It is incredibly helpful and will answer all of your problems.

**Accepting Credit Card payments**

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/accept-credit-cards/

**PayPal API Documentation**

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-payments-overview/

Comment: i mean i am already getting paypal pay option i want to provide also do not have paypal account? direct payment option. so which field i have to pass in form to display 2nd option.

Comment: paypal accepts cards too.  I am not sure what your meaning is.  There should be an option for them to pay without requiring them to have a paypal account.  The first link I gave you includes all details for accepting direct payments.

Comment: i have checked it but which field i have to pass in paypal form to display that option

Comment: Please check this screenshot. you can see pay with debit or credit card option but there is not written not have paypal account? awesomescreenshot.com/0f73wzgr9a

Comment: I looked at your screenshot.  Everything is working the way it should.  You do not need a PayPal account to use the direct payment method.

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to put any extra field for that option, this option comes every time on paypal payment page, if user has not paypal account then he can pay using the link given below the login form as "No PayPal account? Pay using your credit or debit card
" that's it

Comment: Please check this screenshot. you can see pay with debit or credit card option but there is not written not have paypal account?          http://awesomescreenshot.com/0f73wzgr9a

Comment: so user can pay with debit card or credit card option, then what's the problem? can you provide your website link?

Comment: This is working fine,you are doing a one time payment so "Pay with my debit or credit card" option comes, if you were used subscription then you will get option "No PayPal account? Pay using your credit or debit card", for these options paypal has no extra field

Comment: when i first time enter all info then click on review & continue. it required to create new paypal account

Comment: Please change language from top then check there it is displaying ceate paypal account

Comment: No this is not required, you can see "(Optional) Sign up with PayPal for faster checkout in future". so this is optional not required.

Comment: yes but now please first change language from top right corner(Espanol). then try to book. in that there is problem. in english version now it is ok but espanol it required to create paypal account